# Wrong keystroke "5" on Chrome when started using Selenium Chrome WebDriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am executing some automated tests using Selenium, and I discovered that when the keystroke "5" is being sent to Chrome, it will act as a "backspace" instead, and delete the last character typed instead of inserting a number 5.

The problem presents itself only when Chrome is controlled by an automated software, regardless of the fact that the input is being sent by Selenium or wrote manually. Once the instance of Chrome is open, even pressing manually on number 5 will act as a backspace. Instead, if I manually launch the same version of Chrome on the same operating system, the keystroke "5" will work as expected.

I am using Chrome 118 but I tested it also on Chrome 97 with similar results. The operating system is an Azure instance with Ubuntu Linux 22. In the automated instance of Chrome, every other keystroke or symbol works as expected, except the number 5. The issue is not related to the page, as both the website I'm testing and the Google page are displaying the same behavior

Selenium is being launched with the following arguments

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();    
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox","--remote-allow-origins=*");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I tried to add also the argument to specify the keyboard mapping with no different outcome.

```
options.addArguments("--lang=en-GB");
```

When I press the number 5, these events are logged (Right side is the WebDriver version, while the right side is a manually started instance of Chrome:

[image: Chrome WebDriver bug]

In the UI Events, both are showing the keystroke as Backspace, although on the manually started instance it actually types a number 5. In the other version instead, it just types Backspace. Similarly, when typing the number 5 from the numpad, i get a number 5 from the right side, and the keystroke F11 on the left side. Every other key seems to be working regularly.